# mysql_escape_string() function is deprecated use mysql_real_escape_string() Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am running a web app in codeigniter running on server. Here I've a user registration form, which works fine in localhost. But when it comes to server,when I try to register an user,my page shows the error:

`mysql_escape_string() function is deprecated use mysql_real_escape_string() in mysql/mysql_driver`

I tried changing my mysql_driver page but after changing everything goes blank. Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Comment: have you tried updating codeigniter

Comment: both functions deprecated use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)

Comment: I'm using latest version of codeigniter

Comment: Seems you have different versions of php installed locally and on the server. Or your debug settings might be different. Your local environment could be more relaxed when it reports warnings.

Comment: instead of mysql_real_escape_string($email) please use $this->db->escape($email);

Comment: @Arun I guess this is the best solution wonder why nobody is aware of  CI's inbuilt escape function $this->db->escape

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using PHP 5.4 the function mysql_escape_string() is deprecated.So you need to do some changes in mysql driver file.Go to system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php and find the `escape_str` function and replace the functions code with this  code:

```
/**
  * Escape String
  *
  * @param string
  * @param bool whether or not the string will be used in a LIKE condition
  * @return string
  */
 public function escape_str($str, $like = FALSE)
 {
  if (is_array($str))
  {
   foreach ($str as $key => $val)
      {
    $str[$key] = $this->escape_str($val, $like);
      }

      return $str;
     }

  $str = is_resource($this->conn_id) ? mysql_real_escape_string($str, $this->conn_id) : addslashes($str);

  // escape LIKE condition wildcards
  if ($like === TRUE)
  {
   return str_replace(array($this->_like_escape_chr, '%', '_'),
      array($this->_like_escape_chr.$this->_like_escape_chr, $this->_like_escape_chr.'%', $this->_like_escape_chr.'_'),
      $str);
  }

  return $str;
 }
```

It may  help you...